# Results from search bar to be links to individual Profiles

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a search bar that returns the names of the users in my members table. However instead of just their usernames being displayed i would like the results to be links to their individual profiles.

Here is the PHP code for the search bar:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "coursework_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$partialSearch = "%". $_POST['partialSearch'] ."%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username LIKE ? 
                    LIMIT 3");

$stmt->bind_param('s',$partialSearch);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

echo $username;

echo "<div>".$searchResults."</div>";
}
?>
```

This is the actual search bar where the results div is the target div for the ajax:

```
<li><input type="text" name="partialSearch"onkeyup="search(this.value)" placeholder="Search for other users"/></li>

<section id="divider">
<div id="results"></div>
```

ajax:

```
function search(partialSearch){
$.ajax({url:"searchbar.php",type:"POST",data:{partialSearch:partialSearch},success:function(result){
$("#results").html(result);
}});
};
```

Below is the code i have used to generate user profiles:

```
<?php

    function user_profile(){

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "root";
            $dbname = "coursework_db";


            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = 'SELECT memberID, username FROM members;';
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            $users = array();

             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $user[]= $row;
            }

            return $user;

            foreach (user_profile() as $user){
        ?>  
            <p>
            <a href="ViewProfile.php?uid=<?php echo $user['memberID'];?>"><?php echo $user['username'];?></a>
            </p>
        <?php


    }
    }

?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help. Would appreciate opinions and advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to finishing the application. I refactored your code, and added detailed notes to guide your through the changes.

**Search Page**

```
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" name="partialSearch" onkeyup="search(this.value)" placeholder="Search for other users"/>
    </form>

    <section id="divider">
        <div id="results"></div>
    </section>

    <!-- always place scripts just before the ending <body> tag for better performance -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function search(partialSearch) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search_results_ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {partialSearch: partialSearch},
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#results").html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**Ajax Search**

```
<?php
/**
 * Your function names should match their purpose. user_profile() does not accurately define the operations
 * this function will be performing.
 *
 * @param array $usernameToSearch - The username to compare with the database.
 *
 * @return array - A list of users.
 */
function get_users_by_username($usernameToSearch)
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "root";
    $dbname     = "coursework_db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    /**
     * The query below will fetch all of your users from the database.
     *
     *      SELECT memberID, username FROM members
     *
     * You can narrow the results by using the WHERE clause with the LIKE operator:
     *
     *      $sql = 'SELECT memberID, username FROM members WHERE username LIKE "%' . $username . '%"'
     *
     * Learn more about the LIKE clause at: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp
     */
    $sql    = 'SELECT memberID, username FROM members WHERE username LIKE "%' . $usernameToSearch . '%"';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $users = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        /** Renamed from $user to $users to match variable definition. */
        $users[] = $row;
    }

    /** Renamed from $user to $users to match variable definition. */
    return $users;
}


/**
 * Your AJAX request sends a parameter called "partialSearch", which contains the value of the textbox
 * on the search page. You can access that parameter through the PHP global, $_POST.
 *
 * (or $_GET, if the parameter is stored in the url. Such as: www.mywebsite.com?partialSearch=my+search+here)
 *
 * Before you execute get_users_by_username(), you must check if the "partialSearch" parameter exists. This
 * can be done through the empty() function, which essentially checks if the value if $_POST['partialSearch'] is:
 *  - false
 *  - an empty string
 *  - null
 *
 * The NOT operator "!" in front of empty() will flip the value returned by empty(). So if empty() returns true, the
 * NOT operator will flip it to false. This important because we only what the code within the "if" statement to
 * execute if $_POST['partialSearch'] is NOT empty.
 */
if(!empty($_POST['partialSearch'])) {
    /** Store the results of get_users_by_username(), so we can count the number of results without re-running the function. */
    $users = get_users_by_username($_POST['partialSearch']);

    /**
     * Foreach loops with through warnings if user_profile() returns an empty value. Make sure count($users) is > 0
     * before running the loop.
     */
    if(count($users) > 0) {
        foreach($users as $user) {
            print '<p>
                  <a href="ViewProfile.php?uid=' . $user['memberID'] . '">
                      ' . $user['username'] . '
                  </a>
               </p>';
        }
    } else {
        print "<p>No Results</p>";
    }
}

/**
 * In files with only PHP code, you do not need the closing PHP tag.
 *
 * "?>"
 */
```

**User Profile**

```
<?php
/**
 * Fetch user from database by their memberID.
 *
 * @param $id - The user's ID
 *
 * @return array - The user database record.
 */
function get_single_user_by_id($id)
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "root";
    $dbname     = "coursework_db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql    = 'SELECT memberID, username FROM members WHERE memberID = ' . $id;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //Return single user
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    if(!empty($_GET['uid'])) {
        $user = get_single_user_by_id($_GET['uid']);

        if(!empty($user)) {
            print "<h1>Welcome " . $user['username'] . "!";
        } else {
            print "User with ID " . $_GET['uid'] . " doesn't exist.";
        }
    } else {
        //No UID was provided
        print "Please provide a UID to a valid user.";
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Tip 1**
Do not use `mysql` or `mysqli` database connections in your applications. Both connections have been deprecated and are extremely insecure. Take a look at [this](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/how-to-explain-sql-injection-to-anyone/) and [this](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) to learn about SQL injection attacks. To prevent such attacks, use [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059).

**Tip 2**
Define your functions in another file, separate from your HTML. Placing function definitions right next to your HTML **will** become messy very quickly. You can use PHP's `include` and `require` functions to do this. ([learn about it here](http://www.fayazmiraz.com/php-include-vs-require/))

**Tip 3**
Using duplicate code is generally bad practice. You are connecting to your database on two pages (search ajax and profile page) using the same code. I recommend building a database class to handle all of your application's database transactions so you don't have duplicate code. [This will help you with that.](http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/)

### Update

There are a couple of problems with your search bar PHP code:

**First**

The following line from your code will only fetch exact matches:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username LIKE ? 
                LIMIT 3");
```

In order to achieve your desired auto-complete search, you need to add a wildcard to it:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username LIKE '?%' LIMIT 3");
```

The '%' will also include usernames that start with the search value.

**Second**

In the same file, the `$searchResults` variable is not defined. Your result string will always be empty.

You need to change your loop iterate through the results and print a link for each result.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    echo $username;

    echo "<div>".$searchResults."</div>";
}
```

to:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

if($results > 0) {
    foreach($results as $user) {
        print '<p>
            <a href="ViewProfile.php?uid=' . $user['memberID'] . '">
                ' . $user['username'] . '
            </a>
        </p>';
    }
} else {
    print "<p>No Results</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your notes made everything clear and easy to understand. I have made the changes you have suggested. However i still have the same issue, my results from the search bar are not links to the individual profile pages

Comment: I forgot to provide some code which is crucial to the process. hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: The code sample I provided is a complete application and will do what you are asking for. Examine the differences between your search bar code, and the example I provided. You'll see where the links are being appended to the results.

Comment: I updated my answer to include changes you can make to get your desired result without making too many changes.

Comment: I have made the changes but i am receiving this error. Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home//Spark/searchbar.php on line 19.

Comment: The error is saying that your are calling the `bind_param()` method from a variable that is either null or not an object data type (and therefore not an instance of PDO or mysqli). Make sure the variable has been defined before line 19. I am unable to replicate the problem using your code. Have you made any changes that are not in the code you provided?

Comment: Sorry to mess you around but i have reverted to the code that you first provided when you answered my question. This time im getting this error: get_users_by_username() in /home/Spark/searchbar.php on line 11. I have stuck to your code but changed the file name which i have made sure reflects in the code

Comment: Did the error provide any other information? I see the error is being triggered on line 11, but the description you provided doesn't explain why it is being thrown.

Comment: Call to undefined function get_users_by_username() in /home/Spark/searchbar.php on line 11

Comment: Please paste the code for `searchbar.php` in [paste bin](http://pastebin.com) and post the link to it in the comments.

Comment: The function get_users_by_username() needs to be defined inside of that file, or included through another file by using the `include()` or `require()` functions.

Comment: Ah finally, its all working now, thank you so much for your help, you have been great!